# ADX request throttling improvements

Tags: azure-data-explorer, adx

I am getting  `{"code": "Too many requests", "message": "Request is denied due to throttling."}` from ADX when I run some batch ADF pipelines. I have came across this [document on workload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/workload-groups) group. I have a cluster where we did not configured work load groups. Now i assume all the queries will be managed by `default` workload group. I found that `MaxConcurrentRequests` property is 20. I have following doubts.

1. Does it mean that this is the maximum concurrent requests my cluster can handle?
2. If I create a rest API which provides data from ADX will it support only 20 requests at a given time?
3. How to find the maximum concurrent requests an ADX cluster can handle?

Comment: could you please include the full error message? it should include the origin of the throttling (i.e. which policy has this limit defined in it)

Comment: 'TableSetOrAppend', Capacity: 6, Origin: 'CapacityPolicy/Ingestion'.", "@context": { "timestamp": "2021-06-14T07:55:41.3803061Z", "serviceAlias": "XXXXXX", "machineName": "KEngine000000", "processName": "Kusto.WinSvc.Svc", "processId": 9544, "threadId": 7080, "appDomainName": "Kusto.WinSvc.Svc.exe", "clientRequestId": "ADF.ControlCommand;", "activityId": " ", "subActivityId": "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for understanding the reason your command is throttled, the key element in the error message is this: `Capacity: 6, Origin: 'CapacityPolicy/Ingestion'`.

this means - the number of concurrent ingestion operations your cluster can run is 6. this is calculated based on the cluster's *ingestion capacity*, which is part of the cluster's *[capacity policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/capacitypolicy)*.

it is impacted by the total number of cores/nodes the cluster has. Generally, you could:

- scale up/out in order to reach greater capacity, and/or
- reduce the parallelism of your ingestion commands, so that only up to 6 are being run concurrently, and/or
- add logic to the client application to retry on such throttling errors, after some backoff.

additional reference: *[Control commands throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/capacitypolicy#control-commands-throttling)*

Comment: Where can I find the: "Number of nodes in cluster" and "Core count per node"?

Comment: you can use `.show cluster` for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/diagnostics#show-cluster

Comment: Thank you. I increased it to 12 by scaling out and there are still several errors (much less than before) - Is there a way to predict how much do I have to scale or is it a trial and error?